# How to run pod with existing statefulset in kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, scale, kubernetes-statefulset

I used this command to start my statefulset:

```
kubectl scale statefulset my-set --replicas=1
```

But pod is not running.

How could I start pod with existing stateful set "my-set"?

Comment: What message is this command giving you?

Comment: Sorry was not performing right patch.

Answer (score 2):

You can scale a statefulset in different ways:

```
kubectl scale --replicas=1 statefulset/my-set

kubectl scale sts my-set --replicas=1

kubectl patch sts my-set -p '{"spec":{"replicas":1}}'
```